# Error while adding custom title on pages with next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

im having issues while trying to add custom titles to my pages on my app. Im using next.js on version 13.
This is my code:

```
"use client";

export const metadata = {
  title: `Login - ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_NAME}`,
};

import { useState } from "react";

const loginPage = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleFormChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormValues((prevState) => {
      const newValue = value === null || value === undefined ? "" : value;
      return { ...prevState, [name]: newValue };
    });
  };
  return <h1>This is the login page</h1>;
};

export default loginPage;
```

This is the error:

```
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

The thing is if I remove the export const metadata it works perfectly, also, if I add the export const metadata in a server-side component works perfectly, it only happens on client components.

I'm using Windows 11

Did someone experience something like this?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you remove `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_NAME}` from the title?

Comment: I remember having few days ago the same error. I don't think that clients with the `use client` directive accept the `export const metadata` object, only RSCs do.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
For NextJS 13 projects using the /app directory, see the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head#dynamic-metadata) for adding dynamic `<Head>` metadata.
i.e. for OP

---

For NextJS projects using version <= 12 (or version 13 using the /pages directory)

Use the [`next/head` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) for client components, for adding `<head>` elements such as the `title`.
It should be something like:

```js
return (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title>Insert your title here</title>
    </Head>
    <h1>This is the login page</h1>
  </>
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: next/head is for the Next.js app using pages directory and the OP is using the app directory/